# Powershell - Report all Microsoft licenses assigned to all users

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to create a report with all Microsoft licenses assigned to all users.

I know from [PowerShell List all O365 Users and Associated Licenses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867695/powershell-list-all-o365-users-and-associated-licenses)

that I can use MSOnline for this or AzureAD commands too, but I would like to try with Graph.

I was trying to use in a loop

`get-mguserlicensedetail -userid xxxx`

I would like it in the format

| User UPN | SkuPartNumber |
| --- | --- |
| User 1 | License 1 |
| User 1 | License 2 |
| User 2 | License 1 |
| User 3 | License 1 |
| User 3 | License 2 |

Regular `get-mguserlicensedetail -userid user1@example.com`

returns

```
Id                                          SkuId                                SkuPartNumber
--                                          -----                                -------------
TBC6E6Ib4E2h7NkDTvMBp5K4DfPpB-lHg3yAcn9G_T0 f30db892-07e9-47e9-837c-80727f46fd3d FLOW_FREE
TBC6E6Ib4E2h7NkDTvMBp-7E6wa1G91HgSARMkvFTgY 06ebc4ee-1bb5-47dd-8120-11324bc54e06 SPE_E5
```

I tried to use the following (I had it prepared for all users but for testing used a smaller number), based on [PowerShell List all O365 Users and Associated Licenses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867695/powershell-list-all-o365-users-and-associated-licenses) :

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All"

# $all_users = Get-MgUser -All
# $users = $all_users.UserPrincipalName
$users = "user1@example.com", "user2@example.com", "user3@example.com", "user4@example.com"

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $licenses_data = get-mguserlicensedetail -userid $user

    foreach ($x in $licenses_data)
    {
        $licenses = $x.SkuPartNumber
        foreach ($license in $licenses)
        {
            $result = [PSCustomObject]
            @{
                UPN = $user
                License = $licenses
            }
        }
    }
}

$result
Disconnect-MgGraph
```

It returned this:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
UPN                            user1@example.com
License                        SPE_E5
UPN                            user1@example.com
License                        FLOW_FREE
UPN                            user2@example.com
License                        PBI_PREMIUM_PER_USER_ADDON
UPN                            user2@example.com
License                        FLOW_FREE
UPN                            user2@example.com
License                        SPE_E5
UPN                            user2@example.com
License                        POWERAPPS_DEV
UPN                            user3@example.com
License                        PBI_PREMIUM_PER_USER_ADDON
UPN                            user3@example.com
License                        SPE_E5
UPN                            user3@example.com
License                        POWERAPPS_VIRAL
UPN                            user4@example.com
License                        FLOW_FREE
UPN                            user4@example.com
License                        SPE_E5

IsCollectible              : False
DeclaringMethod            : 
FullName                   : System.Management.Automation.PSObject
AssemblyQualifiedName      : System.Management.Automation.PSObject, System.Management.Automation,
```

after is collectible there is a lot more but I do not want to spam this question much more.
I know this aproach is probably really bad but it is my irst time that I try to create a report like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @jdweng for your help.

I have managed to resolve the issue myself - turns out Export-csv simply does what I need (I forgot to underline that I would export the data eventually, my bad here).

Code that is working for me:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All"

$users = "user1@example.com", "user2@example.com", "user3@example.com", "user4@example.com"

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $data = Get-MgUserLicenseDetail -UserId $user
    $data | Add-Member -Name User -Value $user -MemberType NoteProperty
    $data | Export-Csv -Path .\data.csv -Append
}

Disconnect-MgGraph
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
onnect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All"

# $all_users = Get-MgUser -All
# $users = $all_users.UserPrincipalName
$users = "user1@example.com", "user2@example.com", "user3@example.com", "user4@example.com"
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $licenses_data = get-mguserlicensedetail -userid $user

    foreach ($x in $licenses_data)
    {
        $licenses = $x.SkuPartNumber
        foreach ($license in $licenses)
        {
            $result = [PSCustomObject]
            @{
                UPN = $user
                License = $licenses
            }
            $table.Add($result) | Out-Null
        }
    }
}
$table
Disconnect-MgGraph
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately it returns the same as it did for me with a lot more additional data after IsCollectible.

Comment: The format is much better with this code than yours.